# Generar Cookie JS

Tags: javascript, date, cookies

estoy generando una cookie que expire a los 9minutos, pero cuando quiero observarla, tiene 2horas menos que la hora de creación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cookie ha sido creada a las 09:10:00 am y en el expires de la imagen pone a las 07:17 ....

El código es:

```
                if($cookies.get('uuid') != undefined ) {
                    $cookies.remove('uuid');
                }
                var dt = new Date().getTime();
                var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
                    var r = (dt + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
                    dt = Math.floor(dt/16);
                    return (c=='x' ? r :(r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
                });

                var expiresValue = new Date(today);
                expiresValue.setMinutes(today.getMinutes() + 9);
                $cookies.put("uuid",uuid, {'expires': expiresValue});
```

Necesito que la cookie expire en 9 minutos desde su creación, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La hora es correcta, simplemente se muestra como hora en tiempo universal coordinado (u hora Zulu, por eso la Z al final), anteriormente conocido como GMT (Greenwich Mean Time):

```js
let now = new Date();
console.log(now);
```

Estás en España, cuya hora durante el horario de verano es GMT +2 (dos horas sobre el tiempo universal), por tanto verás que "se restan" dos horas al mostrar los valores.